# Ubuntu Desktop 21.10, disappearing cursor

Tags: 20.10, cinnamon

Problem - My mouse cursor randomly disappears after a few seconds of inactivity , sometimes even in 1 sec , I don't like this behaviour , How can i stop it ?

System info - Ubuntu 21.10 , Cinamon desktop

Other info - This problem was also on 20.04

Comment: I am also having this problem, it is so frustrating.  I have found that if I goto my laptop and run a Remmina connection to the system it is up and the desktop works - including the curse - but only in the Remmina connection window.